# Mobile Safari video upload makes site refresh

Tags: node.js, angular, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, adhoc

I created a photo uploading server on a raspberry pi using Angular with Node.Js and multer. This is all hosted on an unsecured ad-hoc network created by the pi itself. The reason I am going for ad-hoc here is because I want to be able to take this on road trips and store photos on it wherever I may be. When I use any mobile browser on my iPhone to upload a video longer than 15 seconds or select a large amount of photos it stalls for a second then refreshes the page which stops the upload. As for error messages I could not see any on Desktop or mobile as the page retunrs with "Something went wrong while displaying webpage" Is there a way to increase multers file size limit?  [Safari iOS refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gz9VI.gif)

HTML for Upload:

```
<div class="dropzone">
<input type="file" #fileDropRef id="fileDropRef" multiple (change)="handleDrop($event)">
<img src="../../assets/upload.png">
<p>Drag and drop here</p>
<p>or</p>
<p>browes for file</p>
</div>
<div id="progressBar" #progressBar></div>
<div id="photoAlbum" #photoAlbum></div>
<div id="gallery" #gallery></div>
```

And to handle the upload

```
handleDrop(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
  console.log(e)

  this.handleFiles(e.target.files)
}

initializeProgress(numFiles) {
  this.progressBar.nativeElement.value = 0
  this.uploadProgress = []

  for(let i = numFiles; i > 0; i--) {
    this.uploadProgress.push(0)
  }
}

handleFiles(files) {
  files = [...files]
  this.initializeProgress(files.length)
  files.forEach(this.uploadFile)
  files.forEach(this.previewFile)
}

uploadFile(file, i) {
  var formData = new FormData();

  formData.append("photos", file);
  formData.append("photos", localStorage.getItem('email'));
  
  var content = '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'; // the body of the new file...
  var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml"});

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      console.log(request.responseText);
  }
}
  request.open("POST", 'http://localhost:port/api/mov/uploadmedia');
  request.send(formData);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this. The problem I was facing was that I was caching a video that surpassed the browser cache limit. To avoid caching I simply used an XMLHttpRequest to upload the file immediately after it is selected. This will stream the file directly to the disk.

```
  counter(e) {
    if(this.i != e.target.files.length){
      this.i++;
      this.handleDrop(e)
    }
  }
  handleDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    console.log(e)

    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("photos", e.target.files[this.i]);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        console.log(request.responseText)
    }
    }
    request.open("POST", 'http://localhost:port/api/mov/uploadmedia')
    request.send(formData)
    this.counter(e)
  }
```